# Why are we still in private beta? What can we do to go public?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Based on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110603/iota) we have relatively decent stats especially for being private. I feel like activity is really slowing down due to the limited scope of the private beta. There are TONS of people who would benefit from the IOTA StackExchange going public that can't access.

How do we go public?

Comment: Slowing down of activity is a normal thing for new sites. Almost every site starts out with a flurry of activity the first three days and then starts settling down to a more normal flow of questions.

Comment: @aboose: We are :-)

Answer (score 9):

#### Update

**This site is now public.**

---

*(original post)*

Private betas typically last about three weeks. Barring any technical delays, this site is slated to go public mid next week around 12/19.