# Accepting Nominations — Who should moderate this site?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderation

Ideally, Moderators♦ are elected by the community, but until the community is large enough to hold a proper election, we will be appointing three provisional Moderators to fill those roles.

We need your help. Please nominate folks you would like to see become provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide valuable insight to help us make our selections. You can read more about the process here: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).**

### The Nomination Process:

- **Nominate a user** by posting an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Use the template at the bottom of this post to complete your nomination.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self-nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- **Tell us about the candidates.** Nominations can include links to other activities like Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **Nominees!** Please indicate your acceptance by editing the answer to accept/decline the nomination. And please ensure your profile email is correct so we can contact you. Optionally, you are encouraged to write a bit about yourself following your acceptance.

  > I accept/decline this nomination.
  >
  > Hi, I am name/location/fun fact (all optional). I live in <location>, so I am generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may want to know about me are…

### Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are looking for members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active during the earliest weeks of this site's creation
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

---

### Nomination Template

To nominate a candidate, copy and paste the text below as an answer and complete your nomination writeup:

> <a href="https://iota.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="https://iota.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   <a href="https://iota.meta.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="https://iota.meta.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   ###Notes:
>   This nominee would be a good choice because …

[image]

Comment: Just an administrative note: With the offices closed over the holidays, things get backed up, so we will not likely start contacting candidates until *after* the 1st week of January.

Answer (score 13):

[image]

[image]
[image: profile for Helmar on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

#### Notes:

This nominee would be a good choice because I have the impression he cares a lot about how the (existing) questions and answers look to a newcomer. His suggestions are friendly and useful. He also probably [has some experience with moderating a beta StackOverflow site](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/a/139) already.

---

*I hereby accept the nominating* because I'm interested in making this Stack Exchange site successful and bringing it from beta to graduation and onward. While I'm certainly not one of the users who brings the most IOTA knowledge—that crown belongs to other people—I would gladly help the site with my moderation experience. IoT applications are also the angle I'm mostly interested in for IOTA.

As mihi already added to this post, I am already a pro-tem moderator on the [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](https://iot.stackexchange.com/) and have been that for almost a year. Therefore I know the ins and outs of the moderator tools and moderating a small SE site. I am also quite reachable in chat as my UTC+1 location allows. Mostly the [Chat of Things](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49682/chat-of-things) currently since this site's chat room is quite abandoned most of the time.

Besides answering, I tend to try help organizing the SE sites I frequent by tending to [editing posts into better shape](https://iota.stackexchange.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white), welcoming new users and [cleaning](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122) up [tags](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9421).

Lastly I won't hide that I'm both an early follower and [critic of how the site came to be](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26968/rushed-proposals-and-community-moderation) and I do think that we have a bit of pruning to do regarding the scope of the site.

Comment: How about yourself, mihi?

Comment: I know that in 2018 I won't be able to be as active on StackExchange as I was in the last days (and in case iota.SE did not launch so far, I probably would have revoked my commitment on area51 (if that is even possible), so I won't nominate myself. But if others nominate me, I won't say no. (Also, I see myself more as a tech person and I know that improving my communication/people skills could definitely not hurt, so I'm probably not the best person for a moderator (more like the one-eyed to the blind) :D)

Comment: I agree with this nomination as well.

Answer (score 13):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I'm nominating mihi -- obvious choice. Most active on this site so far, and strong dedication to making the private beta a success, with a strong technical background in IOTA that I admire. He does a good job of staying objective and answering questions well, and I think he is a great contributor. I think the IOTA StackExchange would be better with mihi as a community leader.

---

*I hereby accept the nomination*

I know that in 2018 I won't be able to be as active on StackExchange as I was in the last few days, which was the reason I did not want to nominate myself. But I'll probably still be able to visit every couple of days and help moderating here.

So far, I don't have any moderator experience (neither here on StackExchange nor elsewhere), and I see myself more as a tech person who is better in answering technical questions than talking to other people (The iota slack drove me crazy, I definitely prefer the StackExchange site). But I guess it is a chance to gather experience in this field and improve my communication skills.

I'm also living in the UTC+1 timezone, and on a typical workday I am only active on the Internet in the evening (7pm or later). And while I try to answer every email I get (which expects an answer) within 24 hours (and so far have succeeded in it), I refuse to get notified on my phone about any email or Internet activity as it distracts me too much and reduces my productivity. Not sure whether this makes me unsuitable for being a moderator, but I'll let the others decide.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

(*My second nomination (I hope it is allowed to nominate more than one person)*)

Second most active user (and he used to be a lot more active than me in the start), and also tries to [push things forward here in meta](https://iota.meta.stackexchange.com/q/40/134). According to the profile he wants

> to contribute to it in any way I know how!

so why not also help here keep the site usable?

---

Thanks mihi for the nomination, which I accept! I have been involved with the IOTA community across several platforms for a few months now. Coming from an economics and finance background, I have learned a lot about the various goals of IOTA, from both a business and technical standpoint. With that said, I am deeply engrossed in IOTA in my day to day as I try to grasp exactly how big of an impact it could have on the IoT and world economy in coming years and consider myself somewhat of an evangelist of the technology, trying to bridge the gap of its vision to the average person.

I do not have much StackExchange experience, even less than that mod experience here, but I am an active moderator of several groups, including a large IOTA Facebook group. That said, I am open minded and definitely feel the need to learn from more pro-SE users as much as possible.

Regardless of outcome I can commit myself to at the very least visiting the SE every single day as I have throughout the beta, going through queues, and answering questions where I feel I have enough expertise and knowledge to contribute something where useful. My end goal, as mihi quoted, is to help IOTA in any way possible, and to ensure those who have better answers or contributions than I can provide are in the spotlight when its the right time. I live in the UTC-8, so a bit offset from the average user here likely.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I nominate myself to be a moderator on this site.

I believe that iota deserves a great high quality stackexchange site.

To reach this high quality, we need experts able to provide top quality answers, and we also need top quality questions to attract those experts.

In this context, I think that moderation in general should be focused on always push users upwards to improve question quality.
At the same time, we are on low traffic site (for now) and we need more and more users: so regarding poor quality questions, I prefer to take the time 
to write a [constructive](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/856/how-many-times-i-gotta-re-attach-before-i-get-the-correct-balace) [comment](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/855/why-there-is-no-radomness-in-tip-selection) instead of close-voting/downvoting immediately. 
I believe that it's probably a friendlier approach for newcomers, and this is sustainable as long as we don't have too many questions per day.

Regarding diamond moderation: stackexchange is mainly moderated by users, the diamond is just there to handle edge cases that can't be handled by the community.
I'm ready to help in this context: I can visit the site almost everyday.
My experience on other sites of the network may help: I know the habits/usages on stackexchange.

Being french native, it isn't always easy to express my view as soon as it is not about purely technical concerns. 
That's why I'm not as active as I should on meta, but I can try to improve this point.

That's it, if you believe that I can help to build this top quality site that IOTA deserves: I'm ready to do it.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

This nominee would be a good choice because Zauz is one of the most active members here at IOTA’s StackExchange. He is a great contributor, who always takes time to provide well-formed, helpful answers and seems to have good understanding and empathy for questions by newbies and first-time visitors what I think is a crucial skill to become a Moderator.

---

#### I accept this nomination.

Hello, I am Zauz. I am a student in Europe so I'm generally active on this site at ~16:00 UTC and sometimes ~7:00 UTC. This of course varies depending on weekday, weekend, holidays, ...

I first learned about cryptocurrencies (and IOTA) some months ago so I'm quite new to this subject. Right now I'm very motivated to learn and help other people learn about Iota and related topics.

I am learning to program for a few years now and always used StackExchange (mainly StackOverflow) to look up questions.

I am also *active* on the iotatangle.slack @Zauz.